# Will Hadoop CapacityScheduler slot reservation scheme cost deadlock?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop CapacityScheduler reserves slots on a TaskTracker if the available memory does not satisfy the need of the job being scheduled ( in TaskSchedulingMgr.getTaskFromQueue(...)). However, will this create any deadlock? Suppose, I have two different jobs from two different queues, each map task needs 3 slots. Each machine has only 4 map slots. At first, when job 1 being scheduled, there are 2 slots available on machine A, so job 1 reserves these 2 slots. Later, when job 2 being scheduled on machine A, another 2 slots become available, so job 2 reserves the remaining two slots. In this case, neither job 1 or job 2 will ever get enough slots to be executed on machine A.

Is there any scheme in the CapacityScheduler preventing this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question! I didn't know the answer either so no better way to check than to run it :)

Lets consider just the Reduce versions of the story, there's two ways to look at this that I can see:

1. needing reduce 3 tasks to complete the reduce phase for the job
2. having reduce tasks that requires three slots worth of virtual
   memory

In both cases the jobs get sent to the Job Tracker a fraction of a second ahead/behind of one another. In **both cases the second job is forced to suspend** until the first completes. No deadlock occurs. Resources are starved from the second until completion. My "guess" as to the reason why there is no such deadlock is that the "remaining unused" resources of the "other" currently unused queue get allocated to the running job to make up the required resources to run it. Hence starving the second, and making suspend.

Naturally a consequence of #2 is that each task is run one at a time, because each task waits until 3 slots are available and hence each task effectively gets executed one at a time. Hope that helps.